# How to properly reconnect to a tcp socket using Boost

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, websocket, tcp

There are similar questions, although none of them quite capture what I'm doing. I haven't setup multiple functions, just a single while loop in my main() function.

I was following a tutorial and have managed to establish a tcp websocket connection for my c++ application, that can accept multiple clients. However if one of those are closed then the application closes and throws this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
terminate called recursively
  what():  The WebSocket stream was gracefully closed at both endpoints
Aborted
```

I'm not sure how to reconnect to the ip, or to have the system constantly listening.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>


using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {

auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1");
auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("8080"));

boost::asio::io_context ioc { 1 };

tcp::acceptor acceptor { ioc, { address, port } };


 while(1)
 {

  tcp::socket socket { ioc };
  acceptor.accept(socket);
  std::cout << "socket accepted" << std::endl;

 }

}
```

**I'd like to have the application stay running and attempt to reconnect if the client gets disconnected.** At the moment the application just shuts down and has to be restarted.

Comment: Catch the exception, and depending on the exception continue or rethrow? Or use the overloads where you pass a reference to an error object that will be filled in? And there must be tons of examples all over the Internet on how to write servers that continue after client disconnects (including in the Boost ASIO documentation).

Comment: I tried to use try and catch statements, but found that was an improper way of doing it. I saw an example to use .reconnect but I'm not sure how to incorporate it if I've written the code in a procedural state. I've not implemented any additional functions to call for when its disconnected. However that may be my best bet.

Comment: It also seems you have some misunderstandings about the server/client setup. If a client disconnects your server should not "reconnect". It should simply free all resources used by that specific client in the server program, and then continue to server other clients. It's up to the *client* to reconnect to the server if the clients needs to.

Comment: That makes sense. So in the case that all the clients disconnect, then the server would potentially remain idle until it receives a tcp based request to connect. Essentially I'd like to have that happen, so potentially it would come down to exception handling. Would you recommend "try and catch" to be the best methods for the handling?

Comment: I haven't used Beast much, but do know ASIO which Beast is using, and in ASIO there are two overloads for almost all socket synchronous operations: One taking an extra argument for error handling, and one without that argument. The functions *without* the error argument will throw exceptions if there's an error. So you have a choice on how to handle errors: Checking the error object, or catching exceptions. Both should work well if implemented correctly. It's up to you to decide which way you prefer. Once you've decided, read the documentation and examples to learn more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will give this a go.